# List user and return non zero exit code if the user not in the system

Tags: command-line, users, command

I need to find a user, and the command should exit with a non-zero return code if the user is not in the system. We can do this in `bash`, but I need this as a line command, not a `bash` script. Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good way of testing whether a user exists on a system is by using `getent`.  The `getent` utility can return various pieces of information from various "databases", for example, the `passwd` "database", the `group` "database", and, on some systems, you can even ask `getent` to list the available login shells.

To test whether a user, `testuser`, is in the system, ask `getent` for the `passwd` entry for that user:

```bsh
getent passwd testuser
```

If this succeeds, you will get a single `passwd` entry as output and a zero exit status from `getent`.  If it fails, you will get no output and a non-zero exit status. I believe that this is the command that you are asking for.

We may discard whatever output the utility generates and use it in an `if` statement, like so:

```bsh
theuser=testuser

if getent passwd "$theuser" >/dev/null
then
    printf 'The user "%s" exists\n' "$theuser"
else
    printf 'The user "%s" does not exist\n' "$theuser"
fi
```

You could instead, of course, parse the `/etc/passwd` file directly with some `grep` command, but that is error-prone (in comparison to using `getent` as shown above) and also would not work correctly on systems where some form of directory service is in use.

Comment: `cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd | grep -Fxq username` is also not all too bad^^ But `getent` is surely better.

Comment: Thanks Kusalananda♦  never heard about getent,thanks for sharing...